# Why does this compile a reference to the class instead of the instance?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
class Foo 
  bar: "hello"
  biz:
    bang: ()=> alert @bar
foo = new Foo()
```

compiles to

```
var Foo, foo;

Foo = (function() {
  var _this = this;

  function Foo() {}

  Foo.prototype.bar = 'hello';

  Foo.prototype.biz = {
    bang: function() {
      return alert(Foo.bar);
    }
  };

  return Foo;

}).call(this);

foo = new Foo();
```

Mainly why does this compile to `alert(Foo.bar);` instead of a reference to the instance?

Comment: You cannot reference the instance from a nested property…

Comment: As a style suggestion you should drop the empty parenthesis from function definitions. Most CoffeeScript code and style guides omit them as well as they are meaningless and `someFunk = ->` is just as valid as `someFunk = () ->`. This suggestion stems from CoffeeScripts goal to remove extraneous parenthesis and brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiles with a reference to the class because you are using `=>` instead of `->`. `=>` binds the `@` of the function to the `@` outside the function. In the case of class functions, the outer `@` of your `bang` function is the class itself.

Using `->` will mean that `@` inside your function depends on how the function is called though, so calling `instance.biz.bang()` will result in `alert(biz.bar)`. Having nested objects like you are attempting is generally confusing. Is there a reason you are trying to do that? I'd say the correct answer here is to just not nest like you are, or else to explicitly do `instance.biz.bang.call(instance)` everywhere, which would be very ugly.

Comment: I needed to namespace some methods but I will likely just separate them into a sub class if it gets confusing to nest them like this.

I guess I could do `biz: ()-> bang:()=> alert @bar` and call `foo.bar().bang()` but that's worse...

Comment: It's not confusing to have nested objects like that - it's not possible. Javascript scoping and assigning of the `this` keyword will prevent the ability for either defintion (`->` or `=>`) from being able to function properly because sub objects are their own objects with their own bindings. At that point, with `->`, `@` refers to `Foo.prototype.biz` while `=>` would make `@` refer to `Foo`, neither of which contains a definition for a `bar` function (which is attached to `Foo.prototype` not `Foo`)

Comment: @izuriel `biz: ()-> bang:()=> alert @bar` would let you nest them in a similar way.

Comment: @boom Yes, but that has nothing to do with this answer or the question so I don't see it's relevance. I didn't say there wasn't a way to pull it off, but that this situation is not confusing because neither option would provide a working (both throw errors) solution.

Comment: @izuriel yeah, I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can namespace methods as you want to, you just need to do it in the right place so that `@` is what you expect it to be. For example:

```
class Foo 
  bar: "hello"
  constructor: ->
    @biz =
      bang: => console.log @bar
foo = new Foo
foo.biz.bang() # 'Hello' in the console.
f = foo.biz.bang
f()            # Also 'Hello' in the console.
```

[**Demo**](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Foo%20%0A%20%20bar%3a%20%22hello%22%0A%20%20constructor%3a%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20@biz%20=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bang%3a%20=%3E%20console.log%20@bar%0Afoo%20=%20new%20Foo%28%29%0Afoo.biz.bang%28%29%0Af%20=%20foo.biz.bang%0Af%28%29)

Note that you **must** use `bang: => ...` inside the constructor to ensure that `@` will be what you expect it to be inside `bang`.

Comment: Cool, good to know, thanks for this example. I think for my situation i'm just going to use sub-classes and pass in the parent.